# SQL Syntax error when using preg_split("/,/",

Tags: php, mysql, twitter, preg-split

I used preg_split to remove the tag info from tweet message-id like, this is original output from Twitter

> tag:search.twitter.com,2005:7551711354822656

I apply preg_split to get rid of 'tag:search.twitter.com' like

```
  $arr = preg_split("/,/", "strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($status->id))");
  $msg_ID =  $arr[1];
```

& insert $msg_ID[1] into table. Now I apply same to message-content whose twitter output is

```
  #DIYse_D  DELIVERAB: twitter messages 1, 9th OCT 2010
```

I apply preg_split to get rid of 'twitter messages 1' from it like

```
  $arr2 = preg_split("/,/", "strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($status->content))");
  $msg =  $arr[1];
```

& insert $msg[1]  into table but it raises sql syntax error. OK, one thing here is that in $ status->id output, twitter added tag at the start of id while here it added 'twitter messages 1' inside the original message contents.
Here is SQL Insert Query

```
INSERT INTO msg2(id,msg,msg_id,depth,name) VALUES ('','$msg','$msg_ID','0','$name')
```

Comment: Could you add your SQL commands?

Comment: @thejh, I added sql insert statement to OP

Comment: Why do you need to use `preg_split()` just to split by a comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr = preg_split("/,/", "strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($status->id))");
                         ^--here                                           ^--here
$arr2 = preg_split("/,/", "strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($status->content))");
                           ^---here                                              ^---here
```

The four double-quotes I've indicated turn those bits of "code" into literal text strings. You're not trying to split the results of a strip_tags function call, you're trying to split a string that says "strip_tags(etc...)". Remove the double quotes so PHP will see that it's a function call, and not a string.

Since there's no commas in that literal string, there won't be any `$arr2[1]` value, so you're trying to insert a blank (or a null) into the database.

As well, change your function sequence to:

```
mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(etc...))
```

Escaping for database insert should be the LAST thing you do before inserting. It's possible that strip_tags may change the ordering of the escapes and produce a 'bad' string, leaving you open to SQL injection attacks.